# Printing out MacOS Mail settings

Tags: bash, macos, email, defaults

Is it possible to dump account settings from MacOS Mail program using some command-line utility? In other words I want to print out (to the Terminal) whatever settings are available in the **Mail** program under **Mail | Preferences | Accounts** menu.

I tried the 'defaults' command but the settings are not there:

```
defaults domains | tr , "\n" | while read r; do defaults read $r; done
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236870

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried `cd ~/Library/Accounts` and then dumped all tables. `for t in $( echo '.tables'|sqlite3 Accounts3.sqlite ); do echo "SELECT * FROM $t;" | sqlite3 Accounts3.sqlite; done` I don't see my accounts (although there is some binary (encrypted?) data in some columns.